# How to convert an Kotlin array of objects into json array with preserving access key names?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have an API which demands the json request to be in specific array form where array object fields are accessed with names which is then posted using Retrofit. Please refer below code:

Kotlin:

```
class RailPoint(
 var railPointId,
 var startTime,
 var endTime
)

var rails: ArrayList<RailPoint>()
rails.add(RailPointObject1)
rails.add(RailPointObject2)
```

So, after converting above `rails` array to json, it should yield following result:

```
{
  "railPoint[0][railPointId]": 5,
  "railPoint[0][startTime]": "",
  "railPoint[0][endTime]": "2021-10-19 07:37:19",
  "railPoint[1][railPointId]": 1,
  "railPoint[1][startTime]": "2021-10-19 07:33:37",
  "railPoint[1][endTime]": "2021-10-19 07:35:20",
}
```

So, how can I achieve this type of json array form?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: my bad, I thought the main question title would do. I have edited my question description.

Comment: Where did you find this sick API? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ugly request, and you might be able to resolve it with an ugly solution :)

I wouldn't suggest this for anything serious, large, or anything that requires some hard and complex maintenance, but if this object will stay that simple (one int and two strings, non-nullable fields) and won't change a lot, you can do it manually:

```
class RailPoint(
    var railPointId: Int,
    var startTime: String,
    var endTime: String
)

val rails = listOf(
    RailPoint(1, "", "2021-10-19 07:37:19"),
    RailPoint(2, "2021-10-19 07:33:37", "2021-10-19 07:35:20"),
)

fun toJson(rails: List<RailPoint>): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    
    rails.forEachIndexed { index, railPoint ->
        sb.append("\"railPoint[$index][railPointId]\": ${railPoint.railPointId},")
        sb.append("\"railPoint[$index][startTime]\": \"${railPoint.startTime}\",")
        sb.append("\"railPoint[$index][endTime]\": \"${railPoint.endTime}\",")
    }

    return "{ $sb }"
}
```

It is very dirty approach, but might be enough, as long as you don't make `RailPoint` more complex, especially, if you don't add members that are custom classes or collections.

(I assumed that times are `String`s, but if they are not, just add some date formatting in the formula)

Comment: Yes, this is the ugliest request I have seen so far and I need to deal with it for some reason. But luckily, the request object won't change much and will stay as is. Thanks for the solution, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by first having Gson serialize the list to a [`JsonArray`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html), then combining the elements in a new [`JsonObject`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and afterwards serializing that object to JSON:

```kotlin
val rails: List<RailPoint> = ...

val gson = Gson()
val railsJsonList = gson.toJsonTree(rails).asJsonArray!!
val railsJsonObject = JsonObject()
// Transform elements
for (i in 0 until railsJsonList.size()) {
    val railPointJson = railsJsonList[i].asJsonObject

    for ((name, value) in railPointJson.entrySet()) {
        railsJsonObject.add("railPoint[$i][$name]", value)
    }
}
println(gson.toJson(railsJsonObject))
```